# How to update multiple documents in firebase using react Web API

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a web based chat application using Firebase and React, and in this application I am trying to manage if the message is seen or not using a `key:value` pair in the collection. The structure of collection is like:

```
chat
    group1
        -MAQ88bAEqaCqzu6RORb
            message: "Hi"
            msgRead: false
            ...
        -MAQ89luju7TEkimtlNd
            message: "Hi"
            msgRead: false
            ...
```

and so on...

I am trying to update the `msgRead` value to `true` in a batch update query like:

```
const db    = firebase.firestore();
let group1  = db.collection("chat").doc("group1");
let batch   = db.batch();
let response= batch.update(group1, 'msgRead', true);
```

but it doesn't effect any document at all. Please some one guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call `batch.commit()` to write the batch.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks

Answer (score 2):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

You should call `batch.commit()`.

ex.

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
var nycRef = db.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

// Update the population of 'SF'
var sfRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
var laRef = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This only works for single objects